# Specifying resource sets in seize block based on agent variable

Tags: anylogic

Agents being pushed through the model have a variable `isMorning` which is set to `false`, but is made `true` if they are injected before a certain time. When the agents enter a seize block, I would like to add a condition that relies on if `isMorning` is `true` or not in order to pick a resource set. I would like to know the proper syntax in using conditionals within the Resource sets parameter to choose between different resource sets, or if this must be done in another parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to create a new function e.g.  `getResoruceSet(boolean isMorning` and then return `ResourcePool[][]`

You can then use this function to replace the resource set parameter in the seize block

[image]

your code inside the function needs to create new arrays for `ResorucePool` where the first dimension is the number of resources that needs to be seized and the second is the different sets.

For example:

```
if (isMorning) {
    return new ResourcePool[][] { 
        { resourcePool, resourcePool }
        };
} else {
    return new ResourcePool[][] { 
{ resourcePool1},       
{ resourcePool, resourcePool2, resourcePool2}
        };

}
```

If it is morning you need to seize 2 units of `resourcePool`. If it is not morning you either need to seize 1 unit from `resorucePool1` or 2 unit from `resourcePool` and 2 from `resorucePool2`