# How to seize resource based on agent condition

Tags: anylogic

I would like to write a code (presumably at Seize > Resources Sets) that allows me to seize from different resources based on agents' paramenter.

I'm developing a health care model where agents are assigned to one specialty (out of 18 possible specialties) using a parameter for that. In the process model they must seize a resource pool that matches the specialty paramenter (currently there is one resource pool for each of the 18 specialties but all of them using the same agent type "Consultant")

I've tried to use a function and then insert in Seize > Resources Set but it is not working.
(I also tried this method explained by Jaco-Ben at: [Specifying resource sets in seize block based on agent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159494/specifying-resource-sets-in-seize-block-based-on-agent-variable) but then comes the error message "cannot convert from Resource Pool[][] to   ResourcePool".

I can't upload images but here goes an attempt to describe what I've got so far:

A model with two agents: Patient and Consultant that are both  initially empty populations. Patient agent has a parameter that define the specialty (int 1 to 3). The model has simple process with a seize block. There are 2 Resource Pool. I just need to seize the Resource Pool that corresponds to Patient's parameter value.

When I use a function, it looks like this:
"Returns Value"
Type: Other -> ResourcePool
no arguments
Then:

that is the only way I can access specialty paramenter

```
for(Patient p:patients){
    if(p.specialty == 1{
    resourcePool;
    } else {
    resourcePool2;
    }
}
 return null;
```

The error message says "Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarator" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration

If I initialize a local variable like:
ResourcePool j;
and then try to make

```
if...
j=ResourcePool
return j;
}
return null;
```

Then the error become
Exception during discrete event execution:
root.seize:
Parameter

But if I retunr j instead of null, then the error becomes:  The local variable j may not have been initialized

Many thanks!

Comment: can you show the properties of your seize block? Jaco's answer require you to choose alternative pools.. did you do that?

Comment: Hi Felipe, thank you for your reply. I didn't try to select alternative pools because actually I will no use alternative pools but specific ResourcePool according to agent's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't show your code, so it's hard to know what exactly is wrong.

In general, you must distinguish between two modes in the settings of Seize block

1. (alternative) resource sets - Here you can define several alternative resource sets
2. units of the same pool - Here you can define `ResourcePool` block from where the resources are requested (For more details, refer to the [Using resources](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/using-resources.html) article)

The first option receives a two-dimensional array of `ResourcePool`, this is also the implementation that appears in the example you mentioned in your question.

But from you I understand that this is not your situation, you want to use one `ResourcePool` at a time and therefore you need to use the second option.

Option to implement your function (after you've defined a ResourcePool population):

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Yossi, thank you very much for you answer. Sorry for not adding my code. I've tried to follow your code but there is something missing and I can't find where (probably it is my limited knowledge in Java).

Comment: I will put my code in my question

Comment: I saw your code,
It's partial, I'm not sure everything is written there correctly. For example: in the first part there is no return, you can't just write resourcePool.
Additionally, make sure that the function has access to the resourcePool if not, you will get an error that the variable is not declarat.

And one more thing, note that it is not certain that you can return null directly into the block. Otherwise you will also get an error. You need a default ResourcePool which you return.